# Format date with timezones in XSL

Tags: xml, apache-fop, xslt-3.0

From XML I receive date in the form of

```
value="2020-08-11T21:00:00.000Z"
```

I live in GMT +3 timezone, so this date should return 2020-08-12. If I simply output the date and display it in browser, it seems that it renders correctly. But when I output it to PDF using apache FOP, it shows only value shown up there.

I tried using  `format-dateTime()` but it outputs the date as the day before.
What else could I try?

Also, substringing is not good here. I need XSLT to automatically add 3 hours (depends on timezone) to the given date so it would return proper date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format-date` and `format-dateTime` take a timezone/place for which you want to format the date or dateTime as the fifth argument so for e.g. `format-dateTime(xs:dateTime('2020-08-11T21:00:00.000Z'), '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01] [z]', 'en', (), 'Asia/Baghdad')` you should get e.g. `2020-08-12 GMT+03:00`.

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6W

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Could you also redirect me on list of locations, because I would probably need to use other than Asia/Baghdad

Comment: I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones but I can't tell for sure whether that list is what the XPath function spec refers to with Olson timezone names. The spec has the link at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#olson and somewhere says it depends on each implementation which version of the timezone database is supported.